# Finding coordinate vector relative to different bases

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been working on coordinate vectors, change of basis, and matrix of linear transformation. However, I don't know how to find the coordinate vector with respect to different bases. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Problem statement:** Let $B=(e_1+e_2,e_1-e_2), B'=(-2e_2,e_1+e_2)$. Both $B, B'$ are bases for $R^2$. Suppose $v \in R^2$ and the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to $B$ is the column vector [-2 6]^t. I have to find the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to $B'$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{aligned}
v&=-2(e_1+e_2)+6(e_1-e_2)\\
&=-2e_1-2e_2+6e_1-6e_2\\
&=4e_1-8e_2\\
&=6(-2e_2)+4(e_1+e_2)
\end{aligned}
hence new coordinates are (6,4).